# Antd DatePicker date does not change in onChange function

Tags: javascript, datepicker, antd

I am using datePicker from antd library and form also from antd.
If I set a field value it does not change in the onChange function. Without defining the field value beforehand everything is ok (onChange2 in codesandbox).
What can be the reason of that?
I prepared sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-gould-9yppt

Comment: can you be more specific ... I don't find any bug in the code.. its working fine. In 2ND datepicker form field you did not set a value in useEffect. That is why 1st datepicker was showing a value, 2nd was not showing. Also, both datepicker do have logs while changing date. I set 2nd datepicker form field value & its showing it .. https://codesandbox.io/s/throbbing-cloud-7wsbs